# Why do I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Error in NodeJS" when trying to run NodeJS commands in the NodeJS REPL?

Tags: node.js

I have this error:

```
> node game.js
node game.js
     ^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
```

[screenshot from PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tv6n.jpg)

When I try to open that javascript file in NodeJS in the PowerShell Terminal(Like I always to do....it used to work before)
I am running this file inside nodejs while I am in the same folder the file is located.
I have used ESLint and run the code on Eprima online validator and the code has no errors.
I have Node Node.js LTS v18.16.0 installed.  It would be great if somebody can help me to fix this issue.

The issue is not the code. I run the code in windows 10 in Chrome with Live Server and is working. The problem is with NodeJS.I am using PowerShell terminal but I also run it from Windows's Command Prompt and the issue persist.

I tried uninstalling NodeJS and installing again, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you're trying to run a (shell) commandline command in the NodeJS REPL. NodeJS is not a [system shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)).

If you want to run that command, exit the NodeJS shell first. You can do that by using the `.exit` [special command](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#commands-and-special-keys). You may also be able to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to exit. Then run the command in your shell where it belongs.

Or if you want to stay in the shell, you could try to `require("game.js")`. There's also the `.load` special command: "*Load JS from a file into the REPL session*".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I realize I don't have to type node at the start of running a program at the VS Code terminal. Just type: `node filename.java` will do, else I  get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Problem solved:)